# jsp character encoding with tomcat 7

Tags: jsp, utf-8, tomcat7

I display messages in my jsp from a properties file that has an encoding "ISO-8859-1"
messages are displayed correctly except for messages buttons or alert box. these are displayed as:Ã©

I have already in my jsp:
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
and also

This issue is found in the transition of my application from tomcat 5 to 7

thnks,

Comment: How does your properties file look like? I suggest your `Ã©` should be `é` - how is it encoded in the properties file? As `\u00E9`?

Comment: words in my properties are like 'é'

Comment: thnks, I solved the problem
it was necessary to declare the Apache filter in the web.xml : org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter